# Error: forEach undefined

Tags: node.js, foreach

I'm having this forEach issue in my code, but I really don't know what is wrong, because for me it's right.
I want to create a route where I can upload an Excel file and based on the file, the code validate the file and accept it or not.

This is the code where forEach appears:

```
router.route('/supply')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('upload');
    })
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        fs.readdir(tmpDir, function(err,data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                if(data.length > 0) {
                    data.forEach(deletaArquivo);
                }
                upload(req, res, function (err) {
                    if (req.fileValidationError || !req.file) {
                        return res.status(500).send({
                            message: "Upload fail. Please select Excel (xlsx) format",
                            error: {}
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send({
                                message: '',
                                error: err
                            });
                        } else {
                            tmpData = importxls.loadExcelFile(req.file.filename, req.body.data, req.body.serial);
                            return res.status(200).send({
                                message: 'Upload succeeded',
                                error: {},
                                data: tmpData
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by `because for me it's right`? [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) defined on Array prototype so `data` is not an array object. I guess its string

Comment: What `node` version you have on server? I was wrong and it should be array based on [fs.readdir docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Comment: Insert this `console.log(typeof data, Array.isArray(data), data);`  right before you do `data.forEach()` and see what you get in the log.

Comment: Also, please include the EXACT error message, word for word.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting `if (err) throw err` to do that's useful.  I see this so often and when put inside an async callback it is basically USELESS.  Implement REAL error handling.  Don't leave it to later.  Write your error handling when you first write the code.  In your particular case, you should probably log the file system error and return a 500 status.

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I wanted to mean that I think it's right, because I've searched in a lot of sites and foruns and can't understand what is wrong

Comment: The node version is v8.10.0